# Black rectangle on top of android camera preview

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-camera2

I am working on android app that uses NDK camera2API with opengl.
When I launch the application on the device, a black rectangle appears on top, although the application should run in full screen.

[image]

The architecture of the application from the java side uses the navigation graph.

To fullscreen mode, I use this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
...
    companion object {

    /** Combination of all flags required to put activity into immersive mode */
    const val FLAGS_FULLSCREEN=
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

    /** Milliseconds used for UI animations */
    const val ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS = 50L
    const val ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS = 100L
    private const val IMMERSIVE_FLAG_TIMEOUT = 100L
}
```

On android side I create texture for usage in cpp:

```
    GLES30.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)
    GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0])
    surfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(textures[0])
```

Shaders:

```
 static const char* vertex_shader_src = R"(
    
    attribute vec3 vertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 uvs;
    uniform mat4 texMatrix; // this from surfaceTexture getTransformMatrix
    varying vec2 varUvs;
    
    void main()
    {
        varUvs = (texMatrix * vec4(uvs.x, uvs.y, 0, 1.0)).xy;
        gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
)";

static const char* fragment_shader_src = R"(
 
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;
    
    uniform samplerExternalOES texSampler;
    varying vec2 varUvs;
    
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler, varUvs);
    }    
  )";
```

Vertex and index

```
static float vertices[] {
        // x, y, z, u, v
        -1, -1, 0, 0, 0,
        -1,  1, 0, 0, 1,
         1,  1, 0, 1, 1,
         1, -1, 0, 1, 0
};
static GLuint indices[] { 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2 };
```

This is render code

```
void ogl::draw_frame(const float texMat[]) {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

glUseProgram(program);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture_id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(tex_sampler, 0);

glUniformMatrix4fv(tex_matrix, 1, false, texMat);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_position);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvs);
glVertexAttribPointer(uvs, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closed.
the problem was that I used the dimensions that the camera used (for example, the camera resolution is 480x640, and the actual window size is 480 x 752, the difference is 112 pixels)